# multiply specific values in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wish to multiply every interger in the column Energy Supply by 1000000 and replace the old integers with the new ones that are multiplyed by 1000000

```
tf = [type(x) == int for x in energy['Energy Supply']]
mid = energy['Energy Supply'].iloc[tf].tolist()
for k in range(len(mid)):
    mid[k] = mid[k]*1000000
replace = energy['Energy Supply'].iloc[tf].tolist()
for k in range(len(mid)):
    energy['Energy Supply'].replace({replace[k]:mid[k]})
```

Thats my code ive been having a hard time to replace them
I would like an easier way to do it but i wont bother if u give me a dirty code

Answer (score 0):

Without real data it's hard to tell. But you can try:

```
# sample data
energy=pd.DataFrame({
    'Energy Supply':[2,'No', 1.1]
})


tf = [type(x) == int for x in energy['Energy Supply']]

energy.loc[tf, 'Energy Supply'] *= 1000000
```

Output:

```
  Energy Supply
0       2000000
1            No
2           1.1
```

Comment: it WORKED thanks so much ive been trying to do this for like three days